# Como obter uma instancia em .net core sem usar construtor

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Normalmente uso o contrutor para obter dependencias algo do tipo:

```
public class Test
{
    private IServiceDependency serviceDependency;
    Test(IServiceDependency serviceDependency)
    {
         _serviceDependency = serviceDependency;
    }
}
```

Como faço para obter a dependencia sem usar o construtor
`GetDependence();` é apenas um método para ilustrar a forma como gostaria de obter a dependência em .net core

```
 public class Test
 {
     private IServiceDependency serviceDependency;
     Test()
     {
        _serviceDependency = GetDependence();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Viu a resposta?

Comment: Não viu? perguntou e não tem interação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu exemplo não condiz com a realidade de Injeção de Dependência que pode acontecer no caso .NET Core de duas formas, pelo construtor ou pelo método, a primeira já sabe como funciona a outra é com [[FromServices]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0) que precede as configurações de um método na declaração das variáveis, por exemplo:

```
public IActionResult Create([FromServices] IServiceDependency dependency) 
{
    dependency....
}
```

Esse tipo de recurso pode ser usado para um ou várias injeções de dependência que é necessário para o seu codigo.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Dependency injection into controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)</sup>